# asio TCP Client breaks when async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, unreal-engine5, asio

I am currently trying to communicate from Unreal Engine 5 with an existing piece of software we have running at our company. This software accepts TCP connections.

Since it seems to be the de-facto standard for C++, I wanted to us asio for this (standalone, without boost). Following some online tutorials and posts I managed to create a working client that connects synchronously and then waits asynchronously for messages. This works as long as the server application is already running when I start the client.

```
//IOSocket.h (excluding function declarations)
static constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
static constexpr int MAX_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS = 3;

std::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> _buffer;
asio::io_context _context;
asio::ip::tcp::endpoint _endpoint;
asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
std::queue<std::string> _outMessageQueue;

//IOSocket.cpp
IOSocket::IOSocket(const std::string& hostname, const uint16_t& port) : _buffer(), _socket(_context) {

    asio::ip::address ip;
    if (hostname == "localhost" || hostname == "loopback") {
        ip = asio::ip::address_v4::loopback();
    } else {
        ip = asio::ip::address::from_string(hostname);
    }

    _endpoint = asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(ip, port);

    asio::io_context::work idle(_context);
    _contextThread = std::thread([this]() {
        _context.run();
    });

    Connect();
}

IOSocket::~IOSocket() {
    Disconnect(false);

    _context.stop();
    if (_contextThread.joinable()) {
        _contextThread.join();
    }
}

void IOSocket::Connect() {
    Disconnect();

    //open TCP socket
    asio::error_code error;
    _socket.connect(_endpoint, error);

    if (error) {
        Disconnect();
        return;
    }

    for (; !_outMessageQueue.empty(); _outMessageQueue.pop()) {
        SendMessage(_outMessageQueue.front());
    }

    //start receive
    ReceiveData();
}

void IOSocket::Disconnect() {
    if (_socket.is_open()) {
        asio::error_code error;
        _socket.shutdown(asio::socket_base::shutdown_both, error);
        _socket.close(error);
    }
}

void IOSocket::ReceiveData() {
    _socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(_buffer), [&](asio::error_code error, std::size_t receviedBytes) {
        if (!error) {
            const std::vector<std::string> msgs = Utilities::String::Split(_buffer.data(), '*');

            for (const std::string& msg : msgs) {
                //Message gets handled by the owner of the IOSocket
            }
            ReceiveData();
        }
    });
}

void IOSocket::SendMessage(const std::string& message) {
    if (_socket.is_open()) {
        write(_socket, asio::buffer(message));
    } else {
        _outMessageQueue.push(message);
    }
}
```

However, I want the client to try connecting at the start for a little while (3 tries with a ten second interval) and when the client already had established a connection and the server disappears, I would like for the client to indefinitely try reconnecting until the server is back again. So I modified the Connect and Disconnect functions to reconnect using a async helper function:

```
//IOSocket.h additions
std::thread _contextThread;
std::future<void> _waitForReconnect;

//IOSocket.cpp
void IOSocket::Connect(int remainingAttempts) {
    Disconnect(false);

    //open TCP socket
    asio::error_code error;
    _socket.connect(_endpoint, error);

    if (error) {
        remainingAttempts--;
        if (remainingAttempts >= 0) {
            int currentAttempt = MAX_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS - remainingAttempts;
            Debug::LogWarning(std::format("Connection attempt {0}/{1} failed: {2}", currentAttempt, MAX_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS, error.message()));
            Disconnect(remainingAttempts > 0, remainingAttempts);
        } else {
            Debug::LogWarning(std::format("Connection attempt failed: {0}", error.message()));
            Disconnect(true);
        }

        return;
    }

    Debug::Log(std::format("Connected to Solid at {0}:{1}", _endpoint.address().to_string(), _endpoint.port()));

    for (; !_outMessageQueue.empty(); _outMessageQueue.pop()) {
        SendMessage(_outMessageQueue.front());
    }

    //start receive
    ReceiveData();
}

void IOSocket::Disconnect(bool tryReconnect, int remainingAttempts) {
    if (_socket.is_open()) {
        asio::error_code error;
        _socket.shutdown(asio::socket_base::shutdown_both, error);
        _socket.close(error);
    }

    if (tryReconnect) {
        _waitForReconnect = Utilities::Delay(10000, [this](int n) { Connect(n); }, remainingAttempts);
    }
}

//Utilities.h
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
static auto Delay(uint32_t delayMilliseconds, Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [=](){
        if (delayMilliseconds > 0) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delayMilliseconds));
        }
        fn(args...);
    });
}
```

This *nearly* works. I get a connection and I can send messages, but I don't receive anything. If I debug and set a breakpoint in any delayed function, the io_context is "stopped" and "outstanding_work" is 0. Even if I restart it and give it new "fake" work to do, I still don't get it process incomming messages.
If I make the innitial connection attempt synchronously (and the server is running), this still produces a functioning connection, but reconnects don't, and if I make the innitial attempt asynchronously, it shows the same behaviour as the reconnects. There is no difference between calling it through my Delay function, an explicit std::thread or a manual std::async call.

I am quite new to asio and I haven't written C++ code in nearly a decade (I am usually using C#), so I am sure there is a lot I am doing wrong, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: FWIW asio has `steady_timer` class with `async_wait()` and `expires_after()`, so you don't need `Utilities::Delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, you seem to be over-complicating things a bit. Here is a simple client that attempts to connect to a server 3 times every 10 seconds, and once it loses connection it will re-attempt indefinitely. Notice there are no threads involved here -- only async operations:

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct client
{
    explicit client(asio::io_context& ctx) :
        socket{ctx}, endpoint{asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), 8080}, timer{ctx}
    { connect_in(0s); }

private:
    tcp::socket socket;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    asio::steady_timer timer;

    std::string data;

    int ttl = 3;
    void connect_in(std::chrono::seconds s)
    {
        if (ttl)
        {
            timer.expires_after(s);
            timer.async_wait([&](asio::error_code ec)
            {
                std::cout << "connect... " << std::flush;

                if (!ec) socket.connect(endpoint, ec);
                if (!ec)
                {
                    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
                    ttl = -1;
                    recv_data();
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "FAILED" << std::endl;
                    if (ttl > 0) --ttl; // maybe negative
                    connect_in(10s);
                }
            });
        }
        else std::cout << "ABANDON" << std::endl;
    }

    void recv_data()
    {
        asio::async_read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(data), '*', [&](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t n)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                auto line = data.substr(0, n);
                line.pop_back();
                data.erase(0, n);

                std::cout << line << std::endl;
                recv_data();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "disconnect" << std::endl;
                socket.close();
                connect_in(10s);
            }
        });
    }
};

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx;
    client client{ctx};
    ctx.run();
}
```

Since I don't have an access to an UE server, here is a simple server that listens for connections and send "ping" messages every few seconds:

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct session
{
    explicit session(tcp::socket s) :
        socket{std::move(s)}, timer{socket.get_executor()}
    {
        std::cout << this << ": create" << std::endl;
        send();
    }

    ~session() { std::cout << this << ": delete" << std::endl; }

private:
    tcp::socket socket;
    asio::steady_timer timer;

    void send()
    {
        timer.expires_after(2s);
        timer.async_wait([&](asio::error_code ec)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << this << ": ping" << std::endl;
                socket.send(asio::buffer("ping*"), { }, ec);
                if (!ec)
                {
                    send();
                    return;
                }
            }

            delete this;
        });
    }
};

struct server
{
    server(asio::io_context& ctx) :
        acceptor{ctx, tcp::endpoint{tcp::v4(), 8080}},
        socket{ctx}
    { accept(); }

private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    tcp::socket socket;

    void accept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [&](asio::error_code ec)
        {
            if (!ec) new session{std::move(socket)};
            accept();
        });
    }
};

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx;
    server server{ctx};
    ctx.run();
};
```

Link to both: https://godbolt.org/z/q9TjnP6Ws

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help, however, while this indeed does establish a connection, it is blocking, so completely unusable. As soon as I hit play in Unreal, it freezes. If the server application is not running, it starts responding again, after the 3 attempts, but if the connection is established, the client just waits indefinitely.

I tried putting the context into its own thread, but then it stops working and doesn't connect, although the server is running.

Comment: So you want non-blocking connect? Your question is lacking MRE, so it's hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Nothing can be allowed block. It needs to run entirely in parallel, even if the server application is not running. The first connection attempt can be exempt, since it happens at startup, but the wait time until the next connection attempt (including the timeout for the connection itself), as well as waiting for data to come in has to be in the background, since the communication with the server is just a small part of the application, and even optional.

Comment: I understand, but you did not answer my question. In my example the only blocking op is `socket.connect()`. The rest are non-blocking. So, do you want non-blocking connect? Or is there another problem?

Comment: If you want everything to run in parallel, then maybe a better option is to make a connect/read/write loop using blocking I/O and just spawn it on a separate thread. You will need synchronization obviously to access shared data.